# Liquibase SQL Server script fails on H2 db tests

Tags: java, sql-server, h2, liquibase

I got liquibase changesets for my SQL Server database, like this

```
<changeSet author="diff-generated" id="1579082307417-3">
        <sql>
            alter table UsersRoles
            add Id int identity
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="diff-generated" id="1579082307417-4">
        <sql>
            alter table UsersRoles
            add constraint UsersRoles_pk
            primary key nonclustered(Id)
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
```

When I'm running app with liquibase on my SQL Server - it works.

But I'm trying to run the same with test - I got an error. Other changesets are executed perfectly.

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in
>   SQL statement "ALTER TABLE USERSROLES
>               ADD CONSTRAINT USERSROLES_PK
>               PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED[*] (ID) "; expected "HASH, ("; SQL statement: alter table UsersRoles
>               add constraint UsersRoles_pk
>               primary key nonclustered (Id) [42001-199]

Settings for liquibase in tests are

```
changeLogFile=classpath:/liquibase/database-changelog.xml
url=jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MODE=MSSQLServer
username=SA
password=
driver=org.h2.Driver
```

I tried to change driver to SQL Server driver, but this doesn't work.
What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

H2 does not support the `NONCLUSTERED` clause from the SQL Server, you need to remove it for H2.

```sql
alter table UsersRoles
add constraint UsersRoles_pk
primary key (Id)
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately i got same error, only without nonclustered in error message. The workaroun i did for now - is to split scripts for h2 and mssql using dbms option of changeset. And for H2 i wrote it using xml notations, not pure sql